# gnome-keyring ssh agent integration not working

Tags: ssh, gnome-keyring

On my system things used to work well, I have a local SSH key defined and I would "ssh <remotesystem>" and gnome-keyring would pop up a dialog asking for the password to decrypt my local SSH key, and then automatically log me in.  Recently, this integration has stopped working and I am looking for help troubleshooting what's broken.  Running seahorse I can confirm that the ssh key appears to be loaded.  From a shell and quick "ps aux" check it looks like both gnome-keyring-daemon and ssh-agent are running, and "echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK" verifies that it is set.  Yet, trying to ssh to the remote system it requests a local password entry, rather than popping up the gnome-keyring GUI to get the password for decrypting my local ssh key.  What more can I do to figure out why this has stopped working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm embarrassed to say it, but I'll post it for the benefit of others :-) ...

My problem was not related to gnome-keyring at all.  The permissions on my ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file (on the system I was trying to log into) had changed, which caused SSH to refuse any login using that key, and hence my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I kill this process, I can get back to typing my passphrase and it works.

```
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
```

I'm looking for a deeper fix.